# Use session id instead of token as authentication to integrate with dropbox http api

Tags: dropbox-api

I use Dropbox http Api v2 to integrate with Dropbox.
I want to perform http request from client side(Javascript).
Because of security reasons I dont want to expose the security token.
Is there a was to pass to the authentication header of the request to Dropbox session id instead of token? 
Other way do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to your own Dropbox account, as opposed to the end-user's own account, you're correct that you shouldn't expose the access token. Client-side applications, such as JavaScript in the end-user's browser, can't keep secrets, so the access token would necessarily be exposed.

Unfortunately the Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to interact with a Dropbox account programmatically, e.g., to upload or download files, without an access token. We'll consider it a feature request though.